# Unable to synchronize Java Script and CGI

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cgi

I am facing a problem in synchronizing  my CGI with web-page. I have one CGI which is written in C Language and is responsible for creating XML file and continuously updating it. My web page reads that XML and displays the content on the page. And Both (CGI and Web-page) are continuously running. Some times when my CGI writing the data in to the xml file, web-page tries to read it at the same time and my function which is written in java script fails to read Data. Is there any way to synchronize this. (Like in linux we use mutex) Something like that.

Some snap of my code which i am using to read XML file:

```
<xml ID="noteXML"
SRC="note.xml"></xml>

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","note.xml?"+ Math.random(),false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Part Of my CGi to create XML

```
void CreateXMLFile()
{
   char buffer[300];

    sprintf(buffer,"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?> \n <note> \n <to>%d</to> \n <status>%s</status> <upgraded>%d</upgraded> <remaining>%d</remaining> \n </note>",100,"Welcom to XML",10,15);

  FILE *xml = fopen("/var/www/html/note.xml","w");

   if(xml)
   {
    fprintf (xml,"%s",buffer);
    fclose(xml);
   }
```

When debugging its giving error in following line (Java Script):

```
        "document.getElementById("to").innerHTML= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use file locking ([`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock)) to mark when a file is in use so you block reading from it until it is updated. You'll probably have to read it through another CGI application so that you can respect the lock.

Better yet - don't store your data in an XML file in the first place. Use an RDBMS and generate the XML on the fly.

Comment: Lock the file before you start writing to it. Unlock it when you finish writing to it. Check for the existence of a lock before reading from it, and if one exists then wait until the lock is gone before continuing.